# Forcing Nib loader use init?(with:) for custom subclass of NSObject in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xib, nib

I add to a XIB custom NSObject, set its class to my subclass of NSObject that conforms NSCoding protocol. Through initialisation UINibLoader use init().

According to Apple’s Resource Programming Guide in iOS any object that conform NSCoding protocol will be send -initWithCoder: message.

Is it possible, and if it is how to force UIKit to use init?(with:) for custom subclass of NSObject?

UPD: My class:

```
class SomeClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

static var sharedSomeClass: SomeClass = {
    return SomeClass()
}()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
}

override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    super.encode(with: aCoder)
}

override func awakeAfter(using aDecoder: NSCoder) -> Any? {
    return SomeClassManager.sharedSomeClass

}
```

}

In XIB I connect to `@IBOutlet var someObject: SomeClass!` in ViewController.

Comment: can you share your sample code?

Comment: @AnandKore updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To force it to use another init method, add the `-initWithCoder` method to your subclass and override it to call your own init method like so:

**Objective-C:** (someone add translation to Swift for me please)

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder(NSCoder*)aDecoder{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if(self){
        [self customInit];
    }

   return self;
}
```

That way when `-initWithCoder` is called, your init method will end up being called. Do the same for `-initWithFrame`

Comment: @antonsergeev88 do the same override approach for the `-initWithFrame` method as well